# Thinking Sphinx indexer condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

My models:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :group
    scope :able, ->{joins(:group).where(:groups => {:disabled => [nil,false]}).order("position")}
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :items
    scope :able, ->{ where(disabled: [false,nil]).order('position') }
end
```

My item_index.rb

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :item, :with => :active_record do
  indexes title
  # attributes
  has created_at, updated_at, group_id, position
end
```

How i can index only Item where group.disabled is false or nil.

Example with where:

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :item, :with => :active_record do
  where "id = 1"
  indexes title
  # attributes
  has created_at, updated_at, group_id, position
end
```

This will index only Item with id = 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your index definition:

```
# force join on groups table:
join group

# PostgreSQL
where "disabled = 'f' OR disabled IS NULL"

# MySQL
where "disabled = 0 OR disabled IS NULL"
```

I'd highly recommend on having a default value of true or false for your disabled column, thus avoiding null values.

Comment: disabled column in groups table. I need something like where "groups.disabled = 'f'".

Comment: Item.joins(:group).where(:groups => {:disabled => [nil,false]}) , i need index only this items